# `sudo` with alias in Bash

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

I have a couple of aliases setup in my `~/.bash_profile` and the same exact ones setup in `/root/.bash_profile` so I can do `v file` instead of `vim file` and etc.

These work fine when I am actually logged in as those users, but when I do something like `sudo v file`, sudo cannot figure out the alias and fails.

Is there a way for sudo to understand aliases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "alias sudo='sudo '" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

**[`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases)**

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next
>   command word following the alias is also checked for  alias 
>   expansion.

Comment: This works! I'll accept the answer as soon as the site will let me (10 mins) How does this work? Edit: Ah! I see. I've read the man page for bash but missed that bit. Thanks alot!

Comment: Great answer, I was not aware of this.